# Where am I going wrong? When I have tested it, for example if I type abc it would output to the canvas aaaaaaaabbbbbbccccccc

Tags: function, debugging, constructor, draw, p5.js

```
function TextTool(){
//set an icon and a name for the object
this.icon = "assets/icons/texttool.jpg";
this.name = "texttool";

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var startingX = 0;



this.event = function() {
    if(mouseX > 0 &&
        mouseX < canvas.width && 
        mouseY > 0 &&
        mouseY < canvas.height
    ) {
        x = mouseX;
        y = mouseY;
        startingX = x;
        return true;
        
    }
    return false;      
};


this.draw = function() {

    if(c.mouseClicked(this.event)) {
        if(keyIsPressed) {
            if(keyCode === ENTER) {
                // Enter key is pressed
                console.log("enter");
                x = startingX;
                y += 15;
            }
            else {
                text(key, x, y);
                console.log('called');
                x += 20;
                
            }    
        } 
    }
    else {
        if(keyIsPressed) {
            if(keyCode === ENTER) {
                // Enter key is pressed
                console.log("enter");
                x = startingX;
                y += 15;
            }
            else {
                text(key, x, y);
                console.log('called');
                x += 20;
                
            }    
        }
    }   
};
```

}

I am trying to create a text tool for my app.
How do I make it so (enter and called) is only called once. Only the this.draw function gets called in the draw function in the sketch file.
I have to use p5.js library for this, can someone help tell me why am I outputting aaaabbbbcccc when i pressed abc.
I used https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked as a guide for the mouseClicked function.
This is my first time using this type of function as usually for the other tool I created I just had to use mousePressed methode which now seem way easier.

Comment: What do you exactly need to do?

Comment: @RuskinWadia I want to it to output in the screen abc if I press abc

Comment: why are you checking whether the mouse is clicked?

Comment: @RuskinWadia because I want it to start typing where the user clicks and start again if the user clicks again

Comment: Alright, will look into it.